# Secured web application with API backend in Laravel

Tags: laravel, api, laravel-passport, laravel-permission, laravel-api

I've created a web application that uses the built-in authentication method for the web, once the user is authenticated he/she is presented with a dashboard page. At this moment Ajax calls to an API need to be made to fetch data for the logged-in user. What would be the correct approach to this to make it is secure?

As a next step, I would like to be able to use the API "stand-alone" as well, so a 3rd party could access the dataset through the API as well.

Right now I am looking into Laravel Passport as well as Spatie Permission package to help me with access control.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using ajax calls in same domain it won't be problem with built-in authentication to give access to authorized users only, because tokens & sessions are accessible for laravel and you can get authenticated users by default.

If you want to make external `api` as well the best approach will be to use [Laravel Passport](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/passport) and pass token in `Authorization` header as usual.

Hope this helps you

Comment: So you would create two guards? e.g. api protected with Laravel Passport and then one eg. api-internal protected with tokens?